# Integration with Emma

Tags: add-on

Does anybody knows what tags are used to get Emma integration with EE (http://myemma.com/email-marketing-integrations/cms-email-integration/expression-engine) to work on templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated MyEMMA GitHub code to get working with EE 2.7.x

To display simple subscribe form use tags below

```
{exp:emma:subscribe} {/exp:emma:subscribe}
```

More here https://github.com/InteractM/integration-emma-expression-engine

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on for MyEmma integration (found [here](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/myemma-integration)), but it is for EE 1.x

You can contact developer for porting it over to EE2, or do that yourself.

Comment: I know about that. EMMA offers their own integration, mentioned above, but there is a lack of documentation how to get this to work (create forms, what tags are using, etc).